# iOS background location updates stops after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, core-location

I try to implement background location tracking but after some time iOS stops my background task. Sometimes it happens after 20 minutes and sometimes after 3 hours. Once the first background task expires and it calls the expiration handler background location tracking stops.

I used approach described here: http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7, https://github.com/voyage11/Location